# fold LaTeX document by \section in AucTeX?

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I can't seem to find examples of how to fold `LaTeX` documents by section headings using `AucTeX` (though I find claims that this is possible and I have not doubt that this is a true statement). Currently -- in the default configuration -- folding the whole buffer seems to just hide the names of the macros and environments but does not fold anything vertically... Any leads? Thanks --

Edit: not sure if this helps, but my `TeX-fold-type-list` is `(env macro math)`, which is the default value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AucTeX supports](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Outline.html) emacs' [outline minor mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Mode.html#Outline-Mode), which does what you want (hint: bind `outline-toggle-children` to something or set `outline-minor-mode-prefix`).

Comment: Ah, needed to look up the `outline-minor-mode` functions (like `hide-body`) rather than doing the show/hide from the menu.

Comment: Just building on @huitseeker's answer. Something like the following would do. `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'outline-minor-mode)
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "<C-tab>") 'outline-toggle-children)`